# When button clicked, expect text to displayed but it cant find the element - protractor

Tags: javascript, html, protractor

I want to click export(download button) and then to confirm i download,
i want to expect that green writing appear on page(for 3-4 seconds only).

Also it downloads the file but i think this way is easier and better than searching for file.

this is code where i do the clicking and expecting

```
productDashboardPageObject.element(by.css('[aria-label="file_download"]')).click();            
expect(element(by.css('.md-flex md-body-l flex')).isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
```

this is before downloading, export button is near filters:

[image: this is before downloading, export button is near filters:]

when i click that export button, after 1 second, that green warning comes:
[image: when i click that export button, after 1 second, that green warning comes:]

this is html of that writing warning: (appears for only a few seconds)
[image: this is html of that writing warning:]

but i got error:

> Message:
>       Failed: No element found using locator: By.cssSelector(".md-flex md-body-l flex")   Stack:
>       NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.cssSelector(".md-flex md-body-l flex")
>           at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
>       Error

Answer (score 3):

The `cssSelector` you are using is incorrect. try using the below locator instead,

```
element(by.css(".md-flex.md-body-l.flex"))
```

Comment: Failed: No element found using locator: By.cssSelector(".md-flex.md-body-l.flex")

Comment: add `browser.wait()` after clicking the export button till the warning alert is displayed.

Comment: i got Failed: fn is not a function
 for browserwait

Answer (score 1):

Using **by.css('.md-flex.md-body-l.flex')** should work.
You probably have some sync issues. You can try to add a sleep when debugging it to make sure that is the locator you want. But I would avoid using waits and sleeps like that. Use an implicit wait that actually waits for the element before clicking it.

I would also avoid having a locator being fetched by using multiple classes from the same element (.class1.class2.class3). It can be quite brittle if some classes are renamed/removed.

Comment: i got Failed: fn is not a function
 for browserwait

Answer (score 0):

I would try using "Elementor" Chrome plugin to get the exact locator for protractor. It is also useful to check a single line of automation code without having to execute everything all the time, in case one is not sure of some element locator.
You can check download and instructions here: https://github.com/andresdominguez/elementor

Before launching it make sure to launch first the standalone selenium webdriver.
Launch elementor via console with the link to the website --> Chrome will open.
Duplicate the tab (otherwise the plugin will crash) and in the second tab open the Chrome DevTools Elements panel, you will find "Protractor" next to the "Styles" pane.
Navigate to the page where you need to find the locator and simply select the element. You will see the locator displayed in the "Protractor" pane.